Curl command execution in Gradle.kts Script
I would like to execute below curl command in my gradle.kts Script. Tried gradle task but command not executable with error [pid=1991, exitValue="Not exited"].
curl -v -H Content-Type:text/plain --upload-file mapping.txt --user Example+account:Example-License-Key-4e8ec2ae6cfe https://api.eum-appdynamics.com/v2/account/Example+account/com.example.networklogger/1/proguard-mapping
I have tried this approach with below Gradle task and expecting to execute curl command.
task.create{
val command = "curl command URL"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
}


Finally for the answer after long dig deep.
Did follow this curl command
tasks.create(name: "uploadMappingFileToAppDynamics") { 

doLast {
exec {
val sourcePath = "${outputsDir)/mapping/selectableEnvironmentRelease/mapping.txt"
commandLine = Listof("curl",
"-X",
"Proxy URL",
"-H",
"Content-Type: text/plain",
"--upload-filel",
"${sourcePath}"
"--User",
"username",
"password")
｝

}
}

You don't have to create a task to just run something in the build script, but you could group up the commands in a run block for example. To wait on a Process result use waitFor().
run {
    val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("curl", "commands URL"))
    val result = process.waitFor()
    println("Result: $result")
}

Sidenotes:
Runtime.exec(String) is deprecated, it's better to use one of the alternatives.
